"Clear all data" option for Google Play resets the email associated with in-app purchases for apps
Note: Many people use "Clear all data" as a quick fix for any Play Store related errors.
In case of multiple accounts in a device where email Y is the default account:

A user has downloaded an app using email X. The in-app purchase dialog shows email X.
From the device app settings, the user clears all data for the Play Store.
The app from step 1 now shows email Y in the in-app purchase dialog.

This is also problematic when a user has made an in-app purchase using email X, and after clearing all Play Store data, the app no longer recognizes the in-app purchase due to a change in associated email.
This issue (above steps 1-3) can also be reproduced in some 3rd party apps like Sketchbook, Realbyte Money Manager.
However, Google apps like YouTube or YouTube music are not affected by this issue. I have observed that it shows the same email id in the in-app purchase dialog that was used to log into the YouTube app.
What does YouTube do to show correct email id in the in-app purchases dialog?
I couldn't find the exact same question and the problem reproduction steps anywhere. I have tried finding a solution from the Android docs and other forums but the only solution mentioned is to reinstall the app using the correct email id from which the purchase is to be made. However, as stated in the question, YouTube somehow shows the correct email id which depends on the email used to log into the YouTube app.
